Opening a jQuery sweetdropdown via method
I am trying to open a popup via the method:
$('#dropdown-standard').sweetDropdown('show');
But this is not working. Nothing happens.
Original code (https://sweet-dropdown.adepto.as/):
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-anchor-top-left dropdown-has-anchor" id="dropdown-standard">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    
<a data-dropdown="#dropdown-standard" class="open-dropdown">Try out!</a>

I tried also with $('#dropdown-standard').click();
With the code below the dropdown will open but it is not visible. So I tried to set the css manually but it is still not working.
$(document).on('click', '#mobileSettingsPopupModal .back-to-dropdown-settings', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dropdown-standard').sweetDropdown('show');
    $('.mobile-header #dropdown-standard').css({'display': 'block !important'});    
});

I tried also with:
$(document).on('click', '#mobileSettingsPopupModal .back-to-dropdown-settings', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a.open-dropdown').click();
    $('.mobile-header #dropdown-standard').css({'display': 'block !important'}); 
});

But the same result. The dropdown is still not visible.
But in both ways i can see in console that the dropdown is opened. But the CSS of the plugin will set display to none every time.
element.style {
    display: none;
}


Documentation suggests that you are supposed to call .sweetDropdown('show') on the trigger element, not the dropdown itself?

Hi, what is the trigger element? Is this a.open-dropdown

Yes, in the above example, that would be it.

I tried with the trigger but still the same problem.

I go to https://sweet-dropdown.adepto.as, type $('button').eq(0).sweetDropdown('show'); into the browser console, and it shows the dropdown for the "can be really [anything]" button. Can't tell what you might be doing wrong from just "I tried"

Ah i tried the same into console and it works outside of the function i wrote:
$(document).on('click', '#mobileSettingsPopupModal .back-to-dropdown-settings', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('a.open-dropdown').sweetDropdown('show');
});
But inside the function like above, it is not working

Do you have any errors on console?

Do you have multiple such dropdowns on the page, perhaps? Then you need to be more specific with the trigger you are actually selecting - because opening one, will close any previously open ones. (If you type $('[data-dropdown]').sweetDropdown('show') into the console on the example page, you'll see what I mean.)

No errors on console.
I have multiple dropdown on the same page, yes. But the trigger class is always different.
